# get_post_meta not working to return GTIN number

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The intention of my `PHP` code below is to display the product `GTIN` number when it is available and display a message when it isn't.  But regardless of whether or not a `GTIN` value exists, it just returns the message.

```
// https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-text-add-cart-single-product-page/   
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_data_above_add_to_cart_button', 6 );
function custom_data_above_add_to_cart_button( $product ) {

// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165757/135006
      if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wccaf_gtin', true ) ) {

        echo '<p>'.get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wccaf_gtin', true ).'</p>';

    } else {

        echo '<p>GTIN unspecified.</p>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `$product->get_id()` instead of `$post->ID`. If you have an older version of wordpress you have to use `$product->id` or a btter solution would be to update the plugin. Since get_id() function is available from version  2.6.0

Comment: It just stalls when I try to load the product page now?

Comment: What woocommerce version do you have installed? Or else what you can do is add `global $post;` at the very beginning of the function

Comment: I tried a variation of your solution: `$product->id`, product page now loads fine but again, the message displays rather than the value.

Comment: Are you sure the meta key **wccaf_gtin** is correct?

Comment: @Omar Tanti Version 3.3.4

Comment: @Omar Tanti How can I check if the meta key is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167392/discussion-between-omar-tanti-and-user136649).

Answer (score -1):

Use like this.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function($product){
if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'wccaf_gtin', true ) ) {
    echo '<p>'.get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'wccaf_gtin', true ).'</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>GTIN unspecified.</p>';
}
}, 6, 1);
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this?  I'm not fluent in PHP, can you explain?

Comment: `get_post_meta ` need post ID as first parameter, and global $post will not work here and you have `$product` object. so you will get post ID from `$product->get_id()`

Comment: And of course you have to make sure this `wccaf_gtin` meta key is corect.